# Ubuntu 19.10 can't login

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm installed vanilla ubuntu 19.10 and rebooting.

When I'm type a password, it returned to login screen (login loop).

I'm runnig terminal by `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and there is no file `.Xauthority` in `~` folder.

Comment: im having the same problem. however i wanted to add the info, that when i switch to a console (like CTRL+ALT+F3) and try to log in as a user , the login works just fine. so its a graphical problem only. ALSO i figgured out, that the graphical login just works fine AFTER i manually restarted GDM3 using " /etc/init.d/gdm3 restart " - btw im having a nvidia grx card. im saying because while searching for help on this issue i found that it seems many nvidia owners seem to have this problem.  an ugly workaround for me was, to install another display manager like lightdm and switch to it.

Answer (score 1):

Setting GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset" in GRUB solved the problem for me.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-increase-tty-console-resolution-on-ubuntu-18-04-server

Comment: Hi! How did that solution relate to the problem that the original poster had?

Comment: i dont know why.... but setting NOMODESET as a kernel argument DID WORK for me on 19.10 with this login problem somehow :/